# Not reading into an array

Tags: c++

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);

char sep = ' ';
string readArray[10];

// Splits the inputted line into separate strings depending on delimiter (' ')
for (size_t p = 0, q = 0, i = 0; p != input.npos && i<readArray.size(); p = q, i++){
    string result;
    result = input.substr(p + (p != 0), (q = input.find(sep, p + 1)) - p - (p != 0)) << endl;
    readArray[i] = result;
}
```

My question is why will the resulting string not read into the readArray? If you find the error can you please fix it because I've been looking at this for while now!

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). **Use a debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: This code doesn't read anything into `readArray` because it doesn't run. It doesn't run because [it doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5c09d8b7a7bf930).

Answer (score 0):

Your `readArray.size()` is wrong, since `readArray` is not a container. You could declare a `std::vector<std::string> readVector;` and use `readVector.push_back(result)`